# Chrome - Very heavy HDD usage. Reading all fonts from 'Fonts' folder

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, browser, fonts, resource-usage

Because of google's bad user support I'm posting this problem here..

```
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!search/hdd$20usage$20fonts/chrome/B207faUB7-Q/_70ST4eN0u0J
```

Now every time I open a new tab or go into google.com my hdd starts cracking like crazy, and white screen until all fonts are read ~ 4 mins before i can browse a page. All fonts are read by google processes. I don't want to ruin my HDD, so I'm using FF now which is using hdd way less..

https://15104268797498972201.googlegroups.com/attach/6d85501a13b4f08c/Untitled.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrE9iJSVRkt7VwlWnOYJHq-KpCmrrshw42pDioBYGverNioa5dIKPyNqXRMSUT1nuDs5W2uoVncxFLVm_QGjexzj_o4vjf3dvLxu17qFg2acLUynIfY

I can't use chrome now because of this, that's why i'm using FF..
Just tried with all plugins disabled  `--disable-extensions` nothing changed, mostly all those fonts are read by new tab page process and google now extension which can't be disabled..

Comment: Why don't you just disable the new font feature.  There is even a question on this very website which how you do that

Comment: If by "font feature" you mean DirectWrite, I just disabled it and seems like everything works fine now, HDD is read/write'in only jumplisticons and cache..